# How can I return to a view without creating repeating versions of the same view?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, segue

I have a split view where the top section of my split shows some questions, and the bottom section shows some other stuff. The problem is that I had it written to "push" to a new view every time the user selects a question. This is obviously less than ideal because the user can enter a situation where they have 15 copies (more or less, depending on how many times the user selects a question) of the same question to go back through.

I thought that a simple solution would be to set a BOOL for when a user selects a question, but as it turns out, this introduces a new bug where the user can select a question once, but if they go back they are out of luck. I'm kind of stuck here, and any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Program flow:

First you need to understand a little about what I am trying to do. I am building a historical inquiry app that focuses on allowing teachers to support student learning of historical inquiry. As such, there are core questions as well as documents the students can analyze.

Based on the way the app has come along, JSLDetailViewController displays the core questions and JSL_QuestionInteraction displays the questions for analyzing the documents.

Relevant code snippet:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        if(!didSelectQuestion){
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"questionDisplaySegue" sender:indexPath];
            didSelectQuestion = TRUE;
        } else {
            JSLDetailViewController *detailView = [JSLDetailViewController alloc];
            detailView.telegram = indexPath.row;
            [detailView setDetailItem:indexPath];
        }
    }else if(indexPath.section == 1){
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"telegramQuestionDisplaySegue" sender:indexPath];
            JSL_QuestionInteraction *questionView = [[JSL_QuestionInteraction alloc] init];
            questionView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"questionDisplaySegue"]){
        JSLDetailViewController *detailView = (JSLDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        detailView.telegram = index.row;
        [detailView setDetailItem:index];
        JSLDetailViewController *controller = (JSLDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"telegramQuestionDisplaySegue"]){
        JSL_QuestionInteraction *questionView = [[JSL_QuestionInteraction alloc] init];
        questionView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any additional details to understand this problem.

Comment: Your structure isn't clear. When they select a question, they go where? JSL_DetailViewController? What happens from there? It would help to give a written description of the flow of the app/

Comment: I added some more information about the app. Does this help? There is obviously more that the app is doing, but this is the functionality I'm worried about right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any of what I write here will fix your problem because I still don't really understand your structure, but I see a couple of things wrong in your posted code.

First, when you're doing segues you shouldn't be alloc init'ing anything in code, the segue instantiates the new controllers for you. It's not clear what you're doing with detailView in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, you do an alloc with no init -- you should **never ever** do an alloc without an init. If that detailView is something that's already present on screen, you should get a reference to that instance and set telegram and detailItem on that.

In the "if" clause of prepareForSegue you are assigning the segue.destinationViewController to two different local variables, detailView and controller -- they both point to the same thing, so there's no reason to have them both.

In the "else" clause, once again your alloc init'ing a controller, which you shouldn't do. You probably want to get the segue's destination view controller instead.

Comment: Thanks! I caught the double-declaration of the detailView and controller when I was staring at the code this evening. The other mistake is because I'm a horrible coder. This is what happens when academics try to learn Objective-C! :-)

Comment: @jelkimantis, well it take quite a long time to master objective-c and cocoa. The problems I see are not as much objective-c as knowing the cocoa framework and how view controllers relate to each other. The "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" linked at the top of the UIViewController Class Reference is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you! It's on my iPad right now and shall read it directly!